# Upload Resized Image To Imgur Without Saving On Disk

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imgur

I am writing a script that will resize an image and then upload it to Imgur - but I don't want to save the image on disk!

```
fp = requests.get(link_of_image)
img = StringIO.StringIO(fp.content)
image = Image.open(img)
im2 = image.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
temp = StringIO.StringIO()
im2.save(temp, 'png')
temp.seek(0)

j1 = requests.post(
    url,
    headers = headers,
    data = {
        'key': api_key,
        'image': temp.read(),
        'type': 'base64',
        'name': '1.png',
        'title': 'Picture no. 1'
    }
)
```

After running this script, I get an error `Image format not supported, or image is corrupt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems your image is not base64 encoded, try changing:

```
    'image': temp.read(),
```

to

```
    'image': temp.read().encode("base64"),
```